Astro page-load event is triggered in other page
I am a Astro begginer. I am using ViewTransitions. I am writting a website with several pages. In index.astro, I have a script which modifies some <a> elements. Therefore, I have written this in the index.astro file:
    <script is:inline>
      console.log("script executed");
      document.addEventListener("astro:page-load", () => {
        console.log("page loaded");`

When I go to the root page of the website, everything works fine, I see that the script is executed and the page-load callback is executed. However, when I go to another page through an anchor, the callback (but not the script) is executed again, why? I don't want that this happens.
I have tried removing the is:inline directive but does not change anything.

ViewTransitions as currently implemented by Astro actually turn what was a MPA (multi-page-app) into a SPA (single-page-app) – that's why. (see e.g. https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/why-astro/ or https://mb21.github.io/blog/2023/09/18/building-a-modern-website-ssg-vs-ssr-spa-vs-mpa-svelte-vs-solid.html#single-page-app-spa-vs-multi-page-app-mpa)

Since the page is not really unloaded when using view transitions, it is important to properly deregister event listeners before the transition occurs. An easy approach is to use the once: true option with addEventListener.
For example:
<script is:inline>
  console.log("script executed");
  document.addEventListener("astro:page-load", () => {
    console.log("page loaded");
  }, {once:true});
</script>

